# Yii webcam extension

Tags: php, yii, webcam, yii-extensions, yii-components

In Yii,Iam using yii-jpegcam webcam extension used for taking photos in my application and it works fine with the following url format

```
index.php?r=user/newphoto
```

But my application is in "/" format (index.php/user/newphoto). So this extension not working with my url format. How it can be solved?

```
 Extension Link used : http://www.yiiframew...on/yii-jpegcam/
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-jpegcam/
```

And my view code is :

```
<?php $onBeforeSnap = "document.getElementById('upload_results').innerHTML = '<h1>Uploading...</h1>';";
      $completionHandler = <<<BLOCK
        if (msg == 'OK') {
            document.getElementById('upload_results').innerHTML = '<h1>OK! ...redirecting in 3 seconds</h1>';

            // reset camera for another shot
            webcam.reset();
            setTimeout(function(){window.location = "index.php?r=user/index";},3000);
        }
        else alert("PHP Error: " + msg);
BLOCK;
      $this->widget('application.extensions.jpegcam.EJpegcam', array(
            'apiUrl' => 'index.php?r=user/jpegcam.saveJpg',
            'shutterSound' => false,
            'stealth' => true,
            'buttons' => array(
                'configure' => 'Configure',
                'takesnapshot' => 'Take Snapshot!'
            ),
            'onBeforeSnap' => $onBeforeSnap,
            'completionHandler' => $completionHandler
        )); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If urlManager enabled in config, you should change apiUrl value with createUrl method :

```
$this->widget('application.extensions.jpegcam.EJpegcam', array(
        'apiUrl' => Yii::app()->urlManager->createUrl('index.php/user/jpegcam.saveJpg'),
        'shutterSound' => false,
        'stealth' => true,
        'buttons' => array(
            'configure' => 'Configure',
            'takesnapshot' => 'Take Snapshot!'
        ),
        'onBeforeSnap' => $onBeforeSnap,
        'completionHandler' => $completionHandler
    ));
```

Comment: Sorry did you tried also to change the url in this line:
setTimeout(function(){window.location = "index.php?r=user/index";},3000);